# PERL: how to detect string encoding so I can use the right charset

Tags: perl, character-encoding

I have these 2 example strings:

```
$a = "點看"; 
$b = "pøp";
```

First one is displayed correctly using charset UTF-8, but second string not.
Second is displayed correctly if charset is changed to iso-8859-1.

I don't know how to display latin1 characters with charset utf-8. 
Or at least, I need a solution to detect string type (e.g this is "utf-8" or this is "iso-8859-1"), so I can use appropriate charset to display it.

Comment: In general, you task is impossible. But [Encode::Guess](http://p3rl.org/Encode::Guess) can help you.

Comment: Hmm, then how others are able to display correctly a mix of Chinese and French/Norwegian characters on the same page? This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Use UTF-8 for all, not UTF-8 for one string and Latin1 for the other.

Comment: [perlunicode](http://p3rl.org/perlunicode)

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why $b is not displayed correctly. I have a ? instead of the right character "ø"

Comment: Where are the strings coming from?

Comment: choroba, these are just 2 examples. I wasn't able to mix French or Norwegian characters with Chinese. With ikegami solution I can use utf-8 charset and everything is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decode inputs. Encode outputs.

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

use utf8;                             # Source code is encoded using UTF-8
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # Terminal expects UTF-8

my $s1 = "點看"; 
my $s2 = "pøp";

say for $s1, $s2;
```

Comment: It worked! Few notes... I'm using perl 5.26. and perl-open is a package which must be installed separately. Also there is a typo inside your code, two $s1 variables instead of $s1, $s2. Thank you very much!

Comment: open.pm is part of Perl itself. It can't even be installed separately. That said, some unix distros love to delete parts of Perl, providing those parts as separate packages even though they are part of Perl itself.

Comment: You're right. I'm using Fedora distro and, to run your script correctly, I had to install package perl-open, due to errors about open.pm not found.

Comment: Also make sure your editor is set to UTF-8. If not, the internal strings may not be read correctly.